# Expenses Calculation Using OOP in PHP

Tags: php, object-oriented

### Raw Data & Analysis Objective

There is a company called Nerdina Entertainment (Nerdina for short). It's been decided to optimize the operation costs of 4 departments (see below). These have 4 types of specialists on staff. Each of the 4 types is characterized by three base properties: pay rate per month, gallons of coffee consumed per month and (just for the fun of it) the amount of code units (whatever this means) produced per month. Additionally, Nerdina employs a system of grades: each employee is assigned a grade that affects their monthly pay rate. Head of a department is a special status that alters all of the base stats. The summary of the available data is in the next sections.

The preliminary goal is to produce a report like this:

```
    +--------------+-------+------------+--------------+------------+---------------+
    |  DEPARTMENT  | STAFF | LABOR COST | COFFEE DRUNK | CODE UNITS | COST PER UNIT |
    +--------------+-------+------------+--------------+------------+---------------+
    | Analytics    |    17 |    142,450 |          102 |      1,037 |         137.4 |
    +--------------+-------+------------+--------------+------------+---------------+
    | Training     |    16 |    129,050 |          102 |      1,265 |           102 |
    +--------------+-------+------------+--------------+------------+---------------+
    | Development  |    36 |    335,150 |          224 |      3,175 |         105.6 |
    +--------------+-------+------------+--------------+------------+---------------+
    | Sales        |    28 |    218,450 |          131 |      1,045 |           209 |
    +--------------+-------+------------+--------------+------------+---------------+
    | TOTAL        |    97 |    825,100 |          559 |      6,522 |           554 |
    +--------------+-------+------------+--------------+------------+---------------+
    | AVERAGE      | 24.25 |    206,275 |       139.75 |    1,630.5 |         138.5 |
    +--------------+-------+------------+--------------+------------+---------------+
```

### Employee Types

Base stats. The figures for pay rate, coffee consumption and code units produced are per month.

```
    +----------+---------+--------+------+
    |   TYPE   | PAYRATE | COFFEE | CODE |
    +----------+---------+--------+------+
    | Manager  |   7,000 |      5 |   75 |
    +----------+---------+--------+------+
    | Marketer |   6,600 |      4 |    5 |
    +----------+---------+--------+------+
    | Engineer |   8,300 |      8 |  200 |
    +----------+---------+--------+------+
    | Analyst  |   7,500 |     12 |  125 |
    +----------+---------+--------+------+
```

NOTE: Heads of the departments earn and drink two times the base figure and don't produce any code.

### Grades

```
    +-------+-----------+
    | GRADE |  PAYRATE  |
    +-------+-----------+
    |   1   |   base    |
    +-------+-----------+
    |   2   | base×1.25 |
    +-------+-----------+
    |   3   |  base×1.5 |
    +-------+-----------+
```

### Staff

E.g. 6×man3 translates to 6 Managers of Grade 3

```
    +--------------+-------------------------------------------------+
    |  DEPARTMENT  |                      STAFF                      |
    +--------------+-------------------------------------------------+
    | Analytics    | 9×man1, 3×man2, 2×ana3, 2×mar1 + chief 1×man2   |
    +--------------+-------------------------------------------------+
    | Training     | 8×man1, 3×mar1, 2×ana1, 2×eng2 + chief 1×man2   |
    +--------------+-------------------------------------------------+
    | Development  | 12×man2, 10×mar1, 8×eng2, 5×ana3 + chief 1×eng3 |
    +--------------+-------------------------------------------------+
    | Sales        | 13×man1, 11×mar2, 3×mar3 + chief 1×man1         |
    +--------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

### My Solution

This is a long one.

```
<?php

/**
 * input.php
 * the input format is determined by me based on the given data.
 * I've been told by the peers that the current one is way too complicated and 
 * the array should look like this:
 * $input = [
 *          ['Analytics', 9, Employee::MANAGER, 1],
 *          ['Training', 8, Employee::MANAGER, 1],
 *          ...
 *          ];
 * Please advise on this point
 */

$input = [
    'Analytics' => [
        [9, Employee::MANAGER, 1],
        [3, Employee::MANAGER, 2],
        [2, Employee::ANALYST, 3],
        [2, Employee::MARKETER, 1],
        [1, Employee::MANAGER, 2, true]
    ],

    'Training' => [
        [8, Employee::MANAGER, 1],
        [3, Employee::MARKETER, 1],
        [2, Employee::ANALYST, 1],
        [2, Employee::ENGINEER, 2],
        [1, Employee::MANAGER, 2, true]
    ],


    'Development' => [
        [12, Employee::MANAGER, 2],
        [10, Employee::MARKETER, 1],
        [8, Employee::ENGINEER, 2],
        [5, Employee::ANALYST, 3],
        [1, Employee::ENGINEER, 3, true]
    ],


    'Sales' => [
        [13, Employee::MANAGER, 1],
        [11, Employee::MARKETER, 2],
        [3, Employee::MARKETER, 3],
        [1, Employee::MANAGER, 1, true]
    ]

];

/**
 * padstring.php
 * a function facilitating the report output later on
 */

function padString($string, $length, $side = "right", $pad = " ") {
    if (strlen($string) == $length) {
        return $string;
    } else {
        $charsNeeded = $length - strlen($string); // 5
        $padding = str_repeat($pad, $charsNeeded);
        ($side == "right") ? ($string = $string . $padding) : ($string = $padding . $string);
        return $string;
    }
}

/**
 * classes.php
 */

abstract class Employee {
    const MANAGER = "Manager";
    const MARKETER = "Marketer";
    const ENGINEER = "Engineer";
    const ANALYST = "Analyst";

    protected int $grade;
    protected bool $chief;

    public function __construct(int $grade, bool $chief = false) {
        $this->grade = $grade;
        $this->chief = $chief;
    }

    /**
     * the following methods are in place to make sure all subclasses
     * include the base properties returned by these methods
     */
    abstract public function getBaseRate();
    abstract public function getBaseCoffeeConsumption();
    abstract public function getBaseCodeProduced();

    public function getActualPay(): float {
        $rate = $this->getBaseRate();
        if ($this->grade == 2) {
            $rate *= 1.25;
        } elseif ($this->grade == 3) {
            $rate = $rate * 1.5;
        }

        return $this->chief ? $rate * 2 : $rate;
    }

    public function getActualCoffeeConsumption(): float {
        return $this->chief ? $this->getBaseCoffeeConsumption() * 2 : $this->getBaseCoffeeConsumption();
    }

    public function getActualCodeProduced(): int {
        return $this->chief ? 0 : $this->getBaseCodeProduced(); 
    }
}

class Manager extends Employee {
    protected $baseRate = 7000;
    protected $baseCoffeeConsumption = 5;
    protected int $baseCodeProduced = 75;

    public function getBaseRate(): float {
        return $this->baseRate;
    }

    public function getBaseCoffeeConsumption(): float {
        return $this->baseCoffeeConsumption;
    }

    public function getBaseCodeProduced(): int {
        return $this->baseCodeProduced;
    }
}

class Marketer extends Employee {
    protected $baseRate = 6600;
    protected $baseCoffeeConsumption = 4;
    protected int $baseCodeProduced = 5;

    public function getBaseRate(): float {
        return $this->baseRate;
    }

    public function getBaseCoffeeConsumption(): float {
        return $this->baseCoffeeConsumption;
    }

    public function getBaseCodeProduced(): int {
        return $this->baseCodeProduced;
    }
}

class Engineer extends Employee {
    protected $baseRate = 8300;
    protected $baseCoffeeConsumption = 8;
    protected int $baseCodeProduced = 200;

    public function getBaseRate(): float {
        return $this->baseRate;
    }

    public function getBaseCoffeeConsumption(): float {
        return $this->baseCoffeeConsumption;
    }

    public function getBaseCodeProduced(): int {
        return $this->baseCodeProduced;
    }
}

class Analyst extends Employee {
    protected $baseRate = 7500;
    protected $baseCoffeeConsumption = 12;
    protected int $baseCodeProduced = 125;

    public function getBaseRate(): float {
        return $this->baseRate;
    }

    public function getBaseCoffeeConsumption(): float {
        return $this->baseCoffeeConsumption;
    }

    public function getBaseCodeProduced(): int {
        return $this->baseCodeProduced;
    }
}

class Department {
    protected string $name;
    protected array $staff;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function addToStaff(Employee $employee) {
        $this->staff[] = $employee;
    }

    public function getStaffNumber() {
        return count($this->staff);
    }

    public function getLaborCost() {
        $laborCost = 0;
        foreach ($this->staff as $employee) {
            $laborCost += $employee->getActualPay();
        }
        return $laborCost;
    }

    public function getCoffeeConsumption() {
        $coffee = 0;
        foreach ($this->staff as $employee) {
            $coffee += $employee->getActualCoffeeConsumption();
        }
        return $coffee;
    }

    public function getCodeProduced() {
        $code = 0;
        foreach ($this->staff as $employee) {
            $code += $employee->getActualCodeProduced();
        }
        return $code;
    }

    public function getCostPerUnit() {
        return round($this->getLaborCost() / $this->getCodeProduced(), 2);
    }

}

class Company {
    protected array $depts;

    public function __construct(array $depts) {
        $this->depts = $depts;
    }

    public function getDepts() {
        return $this->depts;
    }

    public function getTotalStaffNumber() {
        $staffNumber = 0;
        foreach ($this->depts as $dept) {
            $staffNumber += $dept->getStaffNumber();
        }
        return $staffNumber;
    }

    public function getTotalLaborCost() {
        $laborCost = 0;
        foreach ($this->depts as $dept) {
            $laborCost += $dept->getLaborCost();
        }
        return $laborCost;
    }

    public function getTotalCoffeeConsumption() {
        $coffee = 0;
        foreach ($this->depts as $dept) {
            $coffee += $dept->getCoffeeConsumption();
        }
        return $coffee;
    }

    public function getTotalCodeProduced() {
        $code = 0;
        foreach ($this->depts as $dept) {
            $code += $dept->getCodeProduced();
        }
        return $code;
    }

    public function getTotalCostPerUnit() {
        $cost = 0;
        foreach ($this->depts as $dept) {
            $cost += $dept->getCostPerUnit();
        }
        return $cost;
    }

    public function getAverageStaffNumber() {
        return round($this->getTotalStaffNumber() / count($this->depts), 2);
    }

    public function getAverageLaborCost() {
        return round($this->getTotalLaborCost() / count($this->depts), 2);
    }

    public function getAverageCoffeeConsumption() {
        return round($this->getTotalCoffeeConsumption() / count($this->depts), 2);
    }

    public function getAverageCodeProduced() {
        return round($this->getTotalCodeProduced() / count($this->depts), 2);
    }

    public function getAverageCostPerUnit() {
        return round($this->getTotalCostPerUnit() / count($this->depts), 2);
    }

    /**
     * should I use echo or is it better to put the entire report string in a variable
     * and return it?
     */
    public function printReport() {
        $regcol = 15;
        $widecol = 20;

        echo padString('DEPARTMENT', $widecol) . padString('STAFF', $regcol, 'left') . padString('LABOR COST', $regcol, 'left') . padString('COFFEE DRUNK', $regcol, 'left') . padString('CODE UNITS', $regcol, 'left') . padString('COST PER UNIT', $regcol, 'left') . "\n";
        echo padString('=', $widecol, 'right', '=') . padString('=', $regcol, 'right', '=') . padString('=', $regcol, 'right', '=') . padString('=', $regcol, 'right', '=') . padString('=', $regcol, 'right', '=') . padString('=', $regcol, 'right', '=') . "\n";
        foreach ($this->depts as $dept) {
            echo padString($dept->getName(), $widecol) . padString($dept->getStaffNumber(), $regcol, 'left') . padString($dept->getLaborCost(), $regcol, 'left') . padString($dept->getCoffeeConsumption(), $regcol, 'left') . padString($dept->getCodeProduced(), $regcol, 'left') . padString($dept->getCostPerUnit(), $regcol, 'left') . "\n";
        }
        echo padString('=', $widecol, 'right', '=') . padString('=', $regcol, 'right', '=') . padString('=', $regcol, 'right', '=') . padString('=', $regcol, 'right', '=') . padString('=', $regcol, 'right', '=') . padString('=', $regcol, 'right', '=') . "\n";
        echo padString('TOTAL', $widecol) . padString($this->getTotalStaffNumber(), $regcol, 'left') . padString($this->getTotalLaborCost(), $regcol, 'left') . padString($this->getTotalCoffeeConsumption(), $regcol, 'left') . padString($this->getTotalCodeProduced(), $regcol, 'left') . padString($this->getTotalCostPerUnit(), $regcol, 'left') . "\n";
        echo padString('AVERAGE', $widecol) . padString($this->getAverageStaffNumber(), $regcol, 'left') . padString($this->getAverageLaborCost(), $regcol, 'left') . padString($this->getAverageCoffeeConsumption(), $regcol, 'left') . padString($this->getAverageCodeProduced(), $regcol, 'left') . padString($this->getAverageCostPerUnit(), $regcol, 'left') . "\n";
    }
}

/**
 * main.php
 */

function makeDepts(array $input): array {
    $depts = [];
    foreach ($input as $dept => $staff) {
        $currentDept = new Department($dept);
        foreach ($staff as $employeeGroup) {
            $quantity = $employeeGroup[0];
            $type = $employeeGroup[1];
            $grade = $employeeGroup[2];
            $chief = isset($employeeGroup[3]) ? true : false;
            for ($c = 0; $c < $quantity; $c++) {
                $employeeObject = new $type($grade, $chief);
                $currentDept->addToStaff($employeeObject);
            }
        }
        $depts[] = $currentDept;
    }
    return $depts;
}

$depts = makeDepts($input);
$company = new Company($depts);

$company->printReport();
```

I'd appreciate any comments or suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I find it odd that you have declared `padString()` despite php already offering [str_pad()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php).
- I think I'd favor declaring `grade`-based rate multipliers as a configurable lookup array rather than a hardcoded condition block.  This way you can maintain that logic without touching the method.
- There is a lot of duplicated method logic in the Department class, this could be D.R.Y.ed out with a single summing method that is fed the correct method name by which to fetch the correct data.
- The same advice applies to your Company class regarding the repeated summing and averaging methods.
- I recommend that all elements in the `$input` rows be declared with a consistent number of rows.  In other words, you shouldn't need to check if `$employeeGroup[3]` is set.  This way you can unpack the row values into readable individual values from within the nested `foreach()` declaration.  [Demo](https://3v4l.org/SbgZs)

  ```
  foreach ($input as $dept => $staff) {
      foreach ($staff as [$quantity, $type, $grade, $chief]) {
          ...
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! It is immensely helpful. I haven't ever built any meaningful projects yet, so your post provided much TIL knowledge. I had no idea about the existence of `str_pad()` or the nifty format of `foreach` loop that you demonstrated. I've found just two possible syntaxes in the official manual, so I've learnt a great deal from your recommendations, and they've rendered my code so much more concise. I can't thank you enough!

Comment: Family time now.  Later, when I am free.

Comment: Oooof, I'm have a super hard time figuring out formatting on here.
Thank you, @mickmackusa I'm looking forward to your further assessment!

I'm still struggling to come up with declaring a single method that would unify the series of those you mentioned as having duplicated logic. Indeed, pretty much all of my Department and Company methods exhibit this flaw. For instance, Department's getLaborCost(), getCoffeeConsumption() and getCodeProduced() could be summarized into something like this:

Comment: `public function getData() {`
        `$data = 0;`
        `foreach ($this->staff as $employee) {`
            `$data += $employee->callASpecificEmployeeMethod();`
        `}`
        `return $data;`
    `}`

I am sorry, but for some reason selecting this chunk of code and pressing Ctrl+K doesn't yield the desired effect.

Comment: Comments do not enjoy the same formatting niceties.  Backticking is the only way.  Look, this demo isn't instantly ready for your script, but the basic premise is that you have a single method that makes iterated calls of a method based on a passed-in variable.  https://3v4l.org/B7bcC

Comment: Wow! Following your advice I have managed to slash a whole lot of repetitive logic off my code. Thank you so much once again, Matt! I'm not sure if it's okay if I continue to bug you with this code, so if it's not, please just ignore this message!
Printing out the report was the preparatory stage, so now I'm going to have to continue working on it to illustrate some of the ideas that Nerdina's Board of Directors has come up with to optimize the cost of production. They involve various measures like laying some staff off, bumping the salary as well as promotion and demotion of others.

Comment: So what I was going to start with is creating three separate methods within the Company class that would clone the objects contained within the $depts property, alter them and then use them to create three new respective Company objects so that I can use the printReport() method on each of them. This way I can create just one Company object -- $company -- and then call $company->printPlan1(), $company->printPlan2() and $company->printPlan3().
So I was wondering if it's even common practice to declare methods within Class A that spew out objects of the very same Class A?